# Print to local home network based printer from cloud server?

Tags: cloud-computing, printing, network-printer, labeler

I'd like to be able to send a print command to a local network label printer from a web application running on a cloud server.

I've already asked how to do this via code on Stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3534925/how-to-automatically-send-print-job-from-cloud-server-to-printer/3535289#3535289), but I would like to know if this is possible from a network/hardware standpoint.  Are there any "label" printers that I can add to a network?  Can I add the label printer as a print device from another network over the web?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Certainly. The last place I worked we had Zebra 105SL barcode printers all over the place. One was tied to an remote system. The remote site only used one IP, so we just configured our firewall to forward packets from that IP, with a destination port of 515, to the correct printer on our network. The remote system just saw our printer as a network printer on our external IP.

Depending on your application a VPN or similar connection might be more appropriate, but our labels were not sensitive in any way, so we went for simplicity.